# Python BeautifulSoup Unable to parse through each item

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm working on parsing data from a website that I've saved as a local file. I'm able to parse through some text without issue, however, this next issue is where I'm having difficulty. The html that I'm wanting to parse is commented out so I saved the data to a local file and converted to html. I'm able to navigate to tbody, but unable to get each tr. The for loop seems to be stuck on the first iteration.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
from csv import writer


response = requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/buf/2016_roster.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


comments=soup.findAll(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))
body=comments[18]
file=open('file.html.','w')
file.write('<html>')
file.write(body)
file.write('</html>')
file.close()



soup_local = BeautifulSoup(open('file.html'), 'html.parser')
test = soup_local.tbody
    for item in test:
        Number=test.th.get_text()
        print(Number)
```

This is returning 100+ of the same number when I expect ~60 different numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find the element 'tbody' then find all 'th' elements within it. Change the last 5 lines to:

```
soup_local = BeautifulSoup(open('file.html'), 'html.parser')
test = soup_local.find('tbody')
for item in test.find_all('th'):
    Number=item.get_text()
    print(Number)
```

Outputs:

```
49
57
33
26
52
38
53
97
22
2
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I modified the solution slightly to work with the rest of the code.

  for item in test.findAll('tr'):
   Number=item.th.get_text()